# What is wrong with that Dell PowerEdge?

Tags: hardware, dell, dell-poweredge, bios, video

Here is the photo of BIOS splash screen when powered on:
[image: Here is the photo of BIOS splash screen when powered on.]

Did you ever see anything like this?

It continues printing garbage instead of usual messages while booting but it does not boot any medium or show boot options menu.

Tried to remove everything but one DIMM, reset CMOS settings and left overnight with no power and CR2032 battery.

Is it possible to re-flash BIOS without seeing what's on the screen?

Or can I plug a pcie video card but how do I permanently disable onboard video?

What else could be done before replacing the entire mother board?

Comment: Does IDRAC say something interesting? Otherwise you seem to be right, it really looks like corrupted BIOS...

Comment: There is no iDRAC, either express or enterprise. And I don't have any sitting around to fit and check. What do you mean by corrupted BIOS? Is this not a hardware problem then?

Answer (score 4):

> What else could be done before replacing the entire motherboard?

You have bad hardware or a bad BIOS flash. If after replacing all of the other components the only thing left is the motherboard, it's the motherboard.

Comment: 1. Is there a way to find out whether it's definitely bad hardware or just a bad BIOS?

2. Is it possible to re-flash BIOS not looking at the screen? (having another functioning T310 available for training)